# Python Regex - Dictionary inside Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I want to create dictionary based on this data:

**Input**

```
1234STUD
```

**Output**

```
{'student': {'id': '1234', 'name': 'STUD'}}
```

**Here what I do with the regex:**

```
import re
rule = '(?P<student>((?P<id>\d{4})(?P<name>\w{4})))'
text = '1234STUD'
m = re.search(rule, text)
m.groupdict()
```

**And for the current output** (*not what I wanted*):

```
{'id': '1234', 'name': 'STUD', 'student': '1234STUD'}
```

*Can anyone advise me what I should do to get the output that I wanted above?*

*Note:*

This is just an example of my project, the data is more complicated than this, so if there is any way if I do with my way above (using the `m.groupdict()`) and it will generate what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a function that builds the dict you want and returns it.  This should use a pre-compiled regular expression pattern for speed.

```
import re

_pat_student_parser = re.compile(r'((?P<id>\d{4})(?P<name>\w{4}))')

def nested_dict_from_text(text):
    m = re.search(_pat_student_parser, text)
    if not m:
        raise ValueError
    d = m.groupdict()
    return { "student": d }

result = nested_dict_from_text('1234STUD')
print(result)
```

Comment: Just for the record, `re` caches recently used regexes in compiled form, so explicitly compiling the regex is only really necessary for speed if you're using a lot of different regexes.

Comment: @Amber, that's good to know, but when writing a function like this I still think it's a good idea to pre-compile.  It certainly can't hurt.

Comment: @steveha Sure. If nothing else, it often makes for cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a nested dictionary with regex alone. You'll need to post-process the data to create a nested structure.

```
import re
rule = '(?P<id>\d{4})(?P<name>\w{4})'
text = '1234STUD'
m = re.search(rule, text)
result = {'student': m.groupdict()}
```